# matching Arabic word numbers with respective number in dictionary using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, character-encoding

I am trying to match an Arabic number to a number, but it is not working. If it try the same method but without Arabic characters it works perfectly.

```
def Replace(text, wordDict):
    for key in wordDict:
        text = text.replace(key, wordDict[key])
    return text



singular = {
    "واحد" :"1",
    "اثنان" :"2",
    "ثلاتة" :"3"
}

s="ثلاثة"
s=Replace(s,singular)
print(s)
```

The output is `ثلاثة` although it should be 3, which means the replace operation was not performed.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use special characters, you should use Unicode strings. The following code displays `3`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def num_replace(text, wordDict):
    for key in wordDict:
        text = text.replace(key, wordDict[key])
    return text

singular = {
    u"واحد": "1",
    u"اثنان" :"2",
    u"ثلاتة" :"3"
}

s = u"ثلاتة"
s = num_replace(s,singular)
print(s)
```

Read [more about Unicode in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).